# Accessing Facebook messages (or notifications) on iOS

Tags: swift, facebook-graph-api, social-framework, acaccount, acaccountstore

I wish to access the user's unread Facebook messages in my app. I'm using the Accounts framework. Calling `accountStore.requestAccessToAccountsWithType:options:` requires the permissions be given as part of the options.

I want to access `/{user-id}/inbox` [stated in their Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/inbox/). This states that the `read_mailbox` permission is required. [Reading the permissions page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3#reference-read_mailbox), it states:

> This permission is granted to apps building a Facebook-branded client
>   on platforms where Facebook is not already available. For example,
>   Android and iOS apps will not be approved for this permission. In
>   addition, Web, Desktop, in-car and TV apps will not be granted this
>   permission.

In other words: *This is available to basically nobody.*

After such a blow, I feel like I'm pulling at straws here, but I'm wondering if this applies to the Accounts framework login. Their API references the standard Facebook login (with a button and then a permissions screen) and doesn't mention login through the Accounts framework.

So I tried it, and got an iOS UIAlertView asking if I wanted to allow my app to access the given permissions, including the Inbox permission. I tapped "OK", and was granted access. But then calling `accountsWithAccountType:` returns 0 accounts (I have a Facebook account logged in on device).

I'm wondering if anyone's done any further investigation, or knows any more about this?

Answer (score 0):

You should first try testing your app in the explorer https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ and see what comes up.

[image]

Additionally, since you have read the permission page, you will understand that it wouldn't make sense developing the app with this feature unless you are the only using it.